# Can't read node from xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

```
<cities>
  <mode>name</mode>
 <list>
  <item>
   <city id="456172" name="Riga">
   </city>
   <temperature value="287.15" min="287.15" max="287.15" unit="kelvin"/>

levelXML = XML(e.target.data);
trace(levelXML.list.item.temperature);
```

Can't get the temperature value. It shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You're tracing `levelXML.list.item.temperature`, but it has no child text element and will therefore trace an empty string. Try, instead, to trace one of its properties:

`trace(levelXML.list.item.temperature.@value.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your xml like this :

```
<cities>
 <mode>name</mode>
 <list>
  <item>
   <city id="456172" name="Riga">
   </city>
    <temperature  min="287.15" max="287.15" unit="kelvin">
     287.15
    </temperature>
```

and in your as3 you'd be able to write

```
trace(levelXML.list.item.temperature);
```

Otherwise, you can keep your xml but in your as3 you'll need to change to :

```
trace(levelXML.list.item.temperature.@value);
```

the .@ search for attributes (like unit or max in your example)